# Passing data from action to channel gracefully

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels

How to pass data from `Action` to `Channel` in Phoenix.

Let's consider that we have controller `Controller` and channel `Channel`, how do send data from `Action` in `Controller` to corresponding `Channel` connection.

The `"solutions"` we came up with are ugly, we once did it by injecting it into .js file (hackathon), but that's uggly. I was thinking about whether is it possible to pass it via session, because first request of `WS` is get request, but I didn't found proper solution yet.

Consider authentication example. You acquire data via oauth callback and want to pass it to same user but on socket connection on a particular channel.

The problem is that data is aquired via callback. Let’s say that data is secret. I want it to be used in socket connection in particular channel

1. Get data from callback (Controller)
2. Do the thing i dont know
3. Join channel with data from callback (Channel)

Any ideas how to do it properly?

Comment: `broadcast!(MyApp.Endpoint, "some_message", %{body: body})`

Comment: I did not meant broadcasting...

Comment: Then you need to explain what you are trying to do because that is sending data to the channel.

Comment: I have edited the post.

Comment: Pass to a specific topic then. `broadcast!(MyApp.Endpoint, "user:4", %{something: something})` where `4` is the user id that the user is connected to.

Comment: Let me epxand the description even more. The problem is I want to use that data to distinguish users.